# Django: Custom pagination with a shift in ListView

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am using pagination in ListView from _django.views.generic: `paginate_by = 7`
In template i want to display pagination, like this:

`1 2 3 4 ... total_pages`

And when user locates on another page, all range shifts, f.e. user moved to second page (2):

`2 3 4 5 ... total_pages`

Fourth page:

`4 5 6 7 ... total_pages`

And so on.

My first idea was simply inherit Paginator class, where i will override _get_page_range method

```
def _get_page_range(self):
    return range(current_page_number, self.num_pages + 1)
```

and use it in ListView:

`paginator_class = MyPaginator`

The problem is that i can't get current page number in Paginator class. So, the question is: how can i get in Paginator class current page number to implement this pagination?

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.5